# Spoofing UDP checksum using scapy

Tags: python

I'm trying to play with a security tool using scapy to spoof ASCII characters in a UDP checksum. I can do it, but only when I hardcode the bytes in Hex notation. But I can't convert the ASCII string word into binary notation. This works to send the bytes of `He` (first two chars of "Hello world"):

```
sr1(IP(dst=server)/UDP(dport=53, chksum=0x4865)/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname=query)),verbose=0)`
```

But whenever I try to use a variable of `test2` instead of `0x4865`, the DNS packet is not transmitted over the network. This should create binary for this ASCII:

```
test2 = bin(int(binascii.hexlify('He'),16))

sr1(IP(dst=server)/UDP(dport=53, chksum=test2)/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname=query)),verbose=0)
```

When I print `test2` variable is shows correct binary notation representation.

How do I convert a string such as `He` so that is shows in the checksum notation accepted by scapy, of `0x4865` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> test
'0b100100001100101'
>>> type(test)
<type 'str'>
>>> test2
18533
>>> type(test2)
<type 'int'>
```

`bin()` returns a string.  Remove the `bin()` to get an integer, and use that for the `chksum` input.  The following sent out the packet correctly for me:

```
from binascii import hexlify
from scapy.all import *

test2 = int(hexlify('He'),16)
send(IP(dst='127.0.0.1')/UDP(dport=53, chksum=test2)/DNS(rd=1, qd=DNSQR(qname="query")),verbose=0)
```

Comment: You answered this.  Thanks.  I had confused the bin() at beginning.  When I removed it, it returned what I needed and now works.